# Commit contents of sub repo

Tags: git

I'm having trouble googling for this one, hopefully this is not overly duplicated on stackoverflow either.

I'm setting up an automated backup solution on several of my machines to an external hd. When I plug in the hd, a bash script will be run to automatically add, commit and push /home/kyle/ to its own branch on the drive.

My issue is that a folder /home/kyle/projects contains many git repositories, currently being viewed by git as a sub repo. I'm looking for a way to be able to version EVERYTHING (/home/kyle/* as well as the contents of each sub repo, not just its metadata) into the hd. I've looked into submodules, subtrees but I still haven't found a solution.

Comment: note that Git is probably not a good idea for a generic backup solution, because it doesn't handle very well big binary files

Comment: I understand that. I will be ignoring my bin directories